# How to properly specify jcenter repository in maven config?

Tags: maven, gradle, artifactory, bintray, jcenter

In Gradle, I need simply add:

```
  repositories {  
   jcenter()  
  }
```

What is the simplest and proper way to do the same in maven pom.xml or where can I get right url for jcenter repository.

Comment: Yo can use this [settings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44265547/how-to-properly-specify-jcenter-repository-in-maven-config) example. You can use this as [reference](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to define settings.xml like the following. If you define it in `~/.m2/settings.xml` it will be global to your maven. If you define it as a resource of your project you can bind it with the `-s` parameter:

```
mvn -s settings.xml compile
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation='http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd'
          xmlns='http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
    
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>bintray</name>
                    <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>bintray-plugins</name>
                    <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
            <id>bintray</id>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>bintray</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: As of Jun 2020 JCenter is only available over HTTPS. So url adresses here must be changed to https.

Answer (score 23):

Just add a repositories section in your pom:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jcenter</id>
        <name>jcenter</name>
        <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: url can be copied from the upper right corner of the repository page. For example, [Spring releases repository](https://bintray.com/spring/jars) has `https://dl.bintray.com/spring/jars` maven repository url

Answer (score 13):

The official documentation from JFrog JCenter is in:
https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter

Hit the SET ME UP! button on the upper right corner.

[image: SET ME UP!]